# Google Play service error while running the application after importing 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am facing a major issue after importing google play service **'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'**.

My application is compiling properly, but while running I am getting following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

My SDK is latest updated one. Please help to solve the issue. I have tried all possibilities available in net.

Comment: Can you please post whole log from Messages ? Because actual error will be there..!

Comment: Try to restarting your `IDE`

Comment: run Gradle Task with custom command line `build --stacktrace --info` and show the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Google play service jar is conflicting with one of my third party library.

Thanks...